# R Regression model results vary enormously on training/test split and seed

Tags: r, regression, linear-regression, random-seed, lasso-regression

I run a linear regression model, in my case a Lasso regression, in R.
All Tutorials that I found use data partitioning to split the dataset into training data (80%, used to train the model) and test data (20%, used to make the prediction for).

Randomization is used to select which data are used for training and testing.
To have reproducible results, I set a seed using:

```
set.seed(500)
index <- createDataPartition(data$y, p=0.8, list=FALSE, times=1)
training_data <- data[index,]
test_data <- data[-index,]
```

After establishing the whole workflow, I thought I can remove the set.seed() function, because for a robust model it shouldn't matter which of the data are used as training or test data, right?
Running the model without set.seed() or with a varying set.seed() (e.g. set.seed(1), set.seed(230), set.seed(3409), ...), I was afraid to see that the correlating coefficients of the model vary enormously!

I often do not have the same coefficients and also the correlation strength of each coefficient varies. I think that within a robust model, this shouldn't happen, right? Sometimes the most prominent coefficient which has a relative influence of 100% in one model, does not correlate in another model at all.

What do you think about this issue? Is it a problem of fitting a representative model to my data? What is your suggestion about set.seed() - can it be removed, should it be used?

Comment: It depends on your sample size. For large sample sizes, I think your assumptions are fair.

Comment: Is there kind of a minimum sample size or way to compute the minimum sample size, so that you can be sure that the resulting model is quite robust?

Comment: I am not aware of such a method. Besides, when I mentioned large sample size, I really meant to say a sample size large enough such that a pattern is present. As you have not provided any data, we can also not really judge if the behaviour you notice is unreasonable.